# Two groups of conditional props trigger "boolean" is not assignable to "false"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, conditional-types, typescript-conditional-types

I have a group of consistent types and two groups of conditional props like so:

```
export interface Props {
    label: string
    children?: ReactNode | undefined
}

export type OpacityConditionalProp =
    | {
            hasOpacitySlider: true
            opacitySliderState: number | number[]
            opacitySliderSetter: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number | number[]>>
      }
    | {
            hasOpacitySlider?: false | undefined
            opacitySliderState?: undefined
            opacitySliderSetter?: undefined
      }

export type VisibilityConditionalProp =
    | {
            hasVisibilityToggle: true
            isVisible: boolean
            onChangeVisibility: (v: boolean) => void
      }
    | {
            hasVisibilityToggle?: false | undefined
            isVisible?: undefined
            onChangeVisibility?: undefined
      }
```

And in the component I declare it like:

```
const LayerItem: FC<Props & OpacityConditionalProp & VisibilityConditionalProp> = ({
    label,
    hasOpacitySlider,
    opacitySliderState,
    opacitySliderSetter,
    isVisible,
    onChangeVisibility,
    hasVisibilityToggle,
    children,
})
```

It works well when I use it like this:

```
<LayerItem
    hasOpacitySlider={false}
    hasVisibilityToggle={false}
    label="Range statistics"
>
```

or like this

```
<LayerItem
    isVisible={show}
    label="Contours"
    opacitySliderSetter={setOpacity}
    opacitySliderState={opacity}
    hasOpacitySlider
    hasVisibilityToggle
    onChangeVisibility={setShow}
>
```

or like this

```
<LayerItem
    hasOpacitySlider={false}
    isVisible={showBathy}
    label="Bathymetry contours"
    hasVisibilityToggle
    onChangeVisibility={setShowBathy}
>
```

However, it throws an error when I use it like this:

```
const hasOrthoData = Boolean(orthoData)

<LayerItem
    hasOpacitySlider={hasOrthoData}
    hasVisibilityToggle={hasOrthoData}
    isVisible={showOrthoLayer}
    opacitySliderSetter={setOrthoLayerOpacity}
    opacitySliderState={orthoLayerOpacity}
    onChangeVisibility={setShowOrthoLayer}
    label="Orthophoto"
>
```

[image: Error]

I expect that if I pass true to `hasVisibilityToggle` or to `hasOpacitySlider`, it will figure out when to use which type and what to render. However, it doesn't work well when I pass ternary operators to the props of the component, complaining with that error.

Maybe there is a better and clean way to achieve this?

I managed to get this working, but I am not pleased with the solution:

```
<LayerItem
    {...(hasOrthoData
        ? ({
                hasOpacitySlider: true,
                hasVisibilityToggle: true,
                isVisible: showOrthoLayer,
                opacitySliderSetter: setOrthoLayerOpacity,
                opacitySliderState: orthoLayerOpacity,
                onChangeVisibility: setShowOrthoLayer,
                label: 'Orthophoto',
          } as Props & OpacityConditionalProp & VisibilityConditionalProp)
        : ({
                label: 'Orthophoto',
          } as Props))}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path AFAIK. TypeScript compiler isn't smart enough to detect at compile time the different combination of properties you are sending to the `LayerItem` component.

You could make it look cleaner anyways

```
const layerItemProps: OpacityConditionalProp = hasOrthoData
    ? {
            hasOpacitySlider: true,
            opacitySliderState: 1
            ...otherProps
        }
    : {
            hasOpacitySlider: false
            ...otherProps
        }

return (
    <LayerItem
        {...layerItemProps}
        label="Orthophoto"
    />
);
```

`label` prop will go anyways independent of the OpacityConditionalProps.